# Select Distinct date and Count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My sample table structure is:

```
TestDate
----------------------
2013-03-25 14:26:40.830
2013-03-20 13:37:39.763
2012-09-10 14:55:55.667
2013-03-20 13:33:20.480
```

And my query is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TestDate, 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS  TT
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Test bp 
      WHERE 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), p.TestDate, 6) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bp.TestDate, 6)) AS Posts 
 FROM Test p
```

I got a result:

```
TT         Posts
Mar-2013    1
Mar-2013    2
Sep-2012    1
```

But I want a result:

```
TT         Posts
Mar-2013    3
Sep-2012    1
```

But I am unable to find my mistake in my query. Thanks.

Comment: I want a last result as above without modify date time structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to select the rows and count for each month?

If so - try something like this:

```
SELECT  
   YEAR(Testdate), MONTH(Testdate),
   COUNT(*) totalPost
FROM    
   tableName
GROUP BY
   YEAR(Testdate), MONTH(Testdate)
```

**Update:** if you **insist** on formatting that inside SQL Server (which I think is the wrong place to do this...) - then use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, TestDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(TestDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
   YEAR(Testdate), MONTH(Testdate),
   TotalPosts = COUNT(*) 
FROM    
   tableName
GROUP BY
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, TestDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(TestDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
   YEAR(Testdate), MONTH(Testdate)
ORDER BY
   YEAR(Testdate), MONTH(Testdate)
```

Comment: Your query gives a correct result.Thanks. but `Mar-2013` is in same column.and I want `Mar-2013` not 2013 3 in different column.

Comment: Any decent front end can **easily** convert that into whatever format you want..... SQL Server handles the **data** part - let the front end (web page, report writer etc.) handle the display details ...

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its my project requirement to handle Date in sql query so I need same format.Thanks.It Work and I get what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast `DATETIME` into `DATE` first.

```
SELECT  CAST(TestDate AS DATE) DATE_ONLY,
        COUNT(*) totalPost
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY  CAST(TestDate AS DATE)
```